# Convert VBA Email program to HTML

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written an email program to send newest files. Is there a code to convert it to HTML. See code below

```
Sub SendNewestFiles()
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim fldName As String
    Dim sName As String

    fldName = "\\mgamain\DATA\General\TINA FILES\INVOICES TO EMAIL\"
    i = 0
    sName = Dir(fldName)
    Do While Len(sName) > 0

    Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)


    With objMail
        .Subject = "MGA INTERNATIONAL INVOICES"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .Attachments.Add (fldName & sName)
        .Display ' .send
    End With 

    sName = Dir 
    i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Bodyformat should be olFormatHTML if you're wanting a html body.

The options are:
olFormatHTML,
olFormatPlain,
olFormatRichText,
olFormatUnspecified

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211430(v%3Doffice.11)